# compiling ffmpeg with decklink fails on debian

Tags: ffmpeg

Following [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). All dependencies, gcc, nasm, etc. should be up to date. I compiled `ffmpeg` successfully without Decklink library.

Now adding `--enable-decklink` and the required includes from Decklink SDK I get the errors below.

Any ideas?

```
CXX     libavdevice/decklink_common.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wdeclaration-after-statement’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-pointer-to-int-cast’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-pointer-sign’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-std=c11’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:54:0:
libavdevice/decklink_common.h:90:5: error: ‘IDeckLinkAttributes’ does not name a type
     IDeckLinkAttributes *attr;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp: In function ‘int decklink_get_attr_string(IDeckLink*, BMDDeckLinkAttributeID, const char**)’:
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:84:5: error: ‘IDeckLinkAttributes’ was not declared in this scope
     IDeckLinkAttributes *attr;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:84:26: error: ‘attr’ was not declared in this scope
     IDeckLinkAttributes *attr;
                          ^~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:86:28: error: ‘IID_IDeckLinkAttributes’ was not declared in this scope
     if (dl->QueryInterface(IID_IDeckLinkAttributes, (void **)&attr) != S_OK)
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp: In function ‘int decklink_select_input(AVFormatContext*, BMDDeckLinkConfigurationID)’:
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:112:20: error: ‘struct decklink_ctx’ has no member named ‘attr’
         res = ctx->attr->GetInt(attr_id, &supported_connections);
                    ^~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp: In function ‘int ff_decklink_set_configs(AVFormatContext*, decklink_direction_t)’:
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:152:18: error: ‘struct decklink_ctx’ has no member named ‘attr’
         if (ctx->attr->GetFlag(BMDDeckLinkSupportsDuplexModeConfiguration, &duplex_supported) != S_OK)
                  ^~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:152:32: error: ‘BMDDeckLinkSupportsDuplexModeConfiguration’ was not declared in this scope
         if (ctx->attr->GetFlag(BMDDeckLinkSupportsDuplexModeConfiguration, &duplex_supported) != S_OK)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:156:36: error: ‘bmdDeckLinkConfigDuplexMode’ was not declared in this scope
             res = ctx->cfg->SetInt(bmdDeckLinkConfigDuplexMode, ctx->duplex_mode == 2 ? bmdDuplexModeFull : bmdDuplexModeHalf);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:156:89: error: ‘bmdDuplexModeFull’ was not declared in this scope
             res = ctx->cfg->SetInt(bmdDeckLinkConfigDuplexMode, ctx->duplex_mode == 2 ? bmdDuplexModeFull : bmdDuplexModeHalf);
                                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:156:109: error: ‘bmdDuplexModeHalf’ was not declared in this scope
             res = ctx->cfg->SetInt(bmdDeckLinkConfigDuplexMode, ctx->duplex_mode == 2 ? bmdDuplexModeFull : bmdDuplexModeHalf);
                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp: In function ‘int ff_decklink_set_format(AVFormatContext*, int, int, int, int, AVFieldOrder, decklink_direction_t, int)’:
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:190:5: error: ‘BMDDisplayModeSupport’ was not declared in this scope
     BMDDisplayModeSupport support;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:254:45: error: ‘support’ was not declared in this scope
                                            &support, NULL) != S_OK)
                                             ^~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:259:68: error: ‘support’ was not declared in this scope
                                                                   &support, NULL) != S_OK) {
                                                                    ^~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:270:9: error: ‘support’ was not declared in this scope
     if (support == bmdDisplayModeSupported)
         ^~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:270:20: error: ‘bmdDisplayModeSupported’ was not declared in this scope
     if (support == bmdDisplayModeSupported)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp: In function ‘void ff_decklink_cleanup(AVFormatContext*)’:
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:434:14: error: ‘struct decklink_ctx’ has no member named ‘attr’
     if (ctx->attr)
              ^~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:435:14: error: ‘struct decklink_ctx’ has no member named ‘attr’
         ctx->attr->Release();
              ^~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp: In function ‘int ff_decklink_init_device(AVFormatContext*, const char*)’:
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:476:33: error: ‘IID_IDeckLinkAttributes’ was not declared in this scope
     if (ctx->dl->QueryInterface(IID_IDeckLinkAttributes, (void **)&ctx->attr) != S_OK) {
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/decklink_common.cpp:476:73: error: ‘struct decklink_ctx’ has no member named ‘attr’
     if (ctx->dl->QueryInterface(IID_IDeckLinkAttributes, (void **)&ctx->attr) != S_OK) {
                                                                         ^~~~
ffbuild/common.mak:63: recipe for target 'libavdevice/decklink_common.o' failed
make: *** [libavdevice/decklink_common.o] Error 1
```

Comment: A) this is C++, B) perhaps you got wrong includes?

Comment: hmm, how to check? They´ve been taken from the current Blackmagic SDK.

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I "downgraded" to the former SDK 10.11.4 - voilà compilation went fine!

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in FFmpeg and [support for DeckLink SDK 11](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=63c2c83f6eb46743e57a16b47dc2f45185391b00) was added on 15 April 2019, so you'll need a build from this date or later.